# What statistical test is appropriate for the following?

Tags: chi-squared-test

What statistical test is appropriate for the following?

I have student ranking by year (1=freshman, etc), along with their responses to questions that seek to find how developed they are in a number of skills (e.g. for team skills, a 3 would indicate excellent team skills, 1 would be not as developed.)  I am hypothesizing that a student who has been in school longer will have a higher score for each skill.

It has been suggested that I use chi-squared because of the type of data, but I am not sure if this is right.   I am predicting a difference for each year in school, but I am making a directional prediction.

What would you suggest?

Comment: One good option is Jonckheere-Terpstra test. You can learn more about it if you search this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can make student rank to be an ordered factor (hence clarifying that 1, 2 and 3 are categories but with 3>2>1) and use simple linear regression to determine if there is a relation, as in following simple example. The data has been arranged as follows:

```
mydf
  rank answer
1    1      1
2    1      2
3    1      1
4    2      2
5    2      2
6    2      1
7    3      3
8    3      2
9    3      2
```

The rank is an ordered factor where 1,2 and 3 have a constant increase. The answers are also ordered but for simple regression can be considered as numeric:

```
 'data.frame':   9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ rank  : Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "1"<"2"<"3": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
 $ answer: int  1 2 1 2 2 1 3 2 2
```

On performing linear regression with answer as dependent variable and rank as predictor, one can test the relation between the two. The output in R is as follows:

```
Call:
lm(formula = answer ~ rank, data = mydf)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6667 -0.3333 -0.3333  0.3333  0.6667 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.7778     0.1925   9.238 0.0000909 ***
rank.L        0.7071     0.3333   2.121    0.0781 .  
rank.Q        0.1361     0.3333   0.408    0.6973    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5774 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4375,    Adjusted R-squared:   0.25 
F-statistic: 2.333 on 2 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.178
```

This shows that there is trend towards linear (but not quadratic) relation with adjusted R^2 of 0.25 .

Comment: Just to tack on for OP's sake, what you're really testing here is to see whether or not each additional level of `year` (i.e. the older the student), is significantly associated with a higher response score, with $H_0$ being no association. The `Estimate` column will give you the increase in response for each level of `year`, and the $P$ value will give you the significance of that association.  You should also look into **multiple testing correction** if you are going to be doing this once for each response variable, because then you are testing more than 1 hypothesis at once.

Comment: If the OP isn't familiar with R this post may be a bit daunting; some more initial explanation would be useful

Answer (score 2):

You are basically interested in testing for *concordance*, which means that when one quantity (year) increases the other (skill) does as well.  There are various tests you could use, but one is based on something known as Kendall's $\tau$, which for two random quantities $X$ and $Y$ is defined as $P(\text{$X$ and $Y$ are concordant}) - P(\text{$X$ and $Y$ are discordant})$.

Each of these probabilities can be estimated in a straightforward way from the data and a significance test done to determine if $\tau > 0$. (If the sample size is sufficiently large one can use a normal approximation to the null distribution of $\hat{\tau}$.)  Most statistical software packages have methods for performing this test.  You can find more information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient